# How does logrotate work when there are two process use the same file?

Tags: linux, logrotate

For example:

1. Program A is writing log to file "test.log".
2. If logrotate runs, it will rename "test.log" to "test.log.1" first, and then create a new file "test.log".

After step 2, program A does not report any error, but the A's log does not appear in the new file "test.log".

The questions are:

1. Where is the data that A write to file after step 2 ?
2. How can logrotate rename and create new file when another process is writing to the file? (Is any point that I miss about logrotate?)

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

This is very tightly related to how POSIX filesystems work. When you rename a file, it's only the name of the file that is changed, the physical file on the disk will not change. Also, once a file is opened, the process using the file only have a link (through many layers) to the physical file on the disk, the name is only used when opening the file.

That means the program A will still write to the same file, which now has the new name (i.e. `test.log.1` in your example).

A common solution to this problem is to have the log rotation program send a signal (e.g. `SIGHUP` or `SIGUSR1` or similar) to the process. The process will detect this signal and then reopen the logging to use the new file.

Comment: In logrotate source code, one config file uses "kill -HUP" to notify the process. But in my linux PC, the default logrotate.conf does not send singal. I am confused.